# restrict a web browser from streaming or downloading a file in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app which is using a web browser control. In this app I want to restrict all streaming and downloading processes using web browser.

For example, if I click on a song link and if that leads to streaming and playing of that song in the web browser itself, I want to restrict such activity.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Handle [Navigating event of the browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). In the handler check the Uri, if you don't like it you can cancel the navigation.

This approach is not actually very reliable, and definitely should not be used for anything security-related.

It may or may not work for you.

Comment: I tried as you told but web page in the browser does not navigates on other page, the streaming starts on the same web page and song starts playing . Therefore I am unable handle it in navigating event...

Answer (score 0):

OK, plan “B”.

You can handle browser’s [Navigated event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigated%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), in this event call `browser.InvokeScript( "eval", JavaScriptSource );` where `JavaScriptSource` is the JavaScript code that alters the behavior of your target web site however you want.

The downside of this approach — your JS will likely stop working as soon as the web site owner change their JS to incompatible. If you’re the web site owner, you’re fine with that.